# How to display app download widget on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, browser

I want to show app download widget on mobile browser when user visits my website on mobile devices. I'm not sure what exactly it is called so can't search for the same. Can anyone help me how to do it? Attaching an example of the same.

[image]

Comment: [Smart App Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) may be the proper term that you are looking for.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

It's called Native App Install Prompt and google got an [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native) about that on their page.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks for quick reply.